# Single field extraction from a database using lambda

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, lambda

My problem is connected to the extraction method called lambda ( I am using it in C# ). I have a database and in it I have a table called Students and I wonder if I would be able to extract the firstName and lastName of certain student whose ID matches my search.

I have tried a few things so far without any luck.

A bit of code from my last attempt :

```
var studentName =
    context.Student //context is the variable with the entities and Student is the table
    .Where(student => student.StudentID == SomeInt) // extract only the one with the chosen ID
    .Select(student => student.FirstName) // tryng only to select the wanted field(s)
    .ToString() // since I want it to be displayed in a textbox
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you're calling `Select` on an `IQueryable<string>` - your query represents a *sequence* of student first names, even if it only matches a single one.

If you only want a single name, you can use:

```
var studentName =
    context.Student
           .Where(student => student.StudentID == SomeInt)
           .Select(student => student.FirstName)
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Then assuming `FirstName` is a string, you don't need `ToString()` at all. The value will be `null` if there's no student with that ID. Alternatively, you could use `Single()`, `SingleOrDefault()`, `First()`, `Last()` or `LastOrDefault()`. So for example, you'd then use:

```
if (studentName == null)
{
    // No match found. Return an error or whatever.
}
else
{
    // Use studentName
}
```

(You should only use `FirstOrDefault()` if you then check for nullity, or pass it on to something else that does so. Otherwise you can end up with a `NullReferenceException` later which is hard to diagnose.)

If you want both the first *and* last names, you need to change your projection. For example:

```
var studentName =
    context.Student
           .Where(student => student.StudentID == SomeInt)
           .Select(student => new { student.FirstName, student.LastName })
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Now the type of `studentName` will be an anonymous type - again, it'll be null if there are no matches, but otherwise it will have appropriate `FirstName` and `LastName` properties.

Comment: I extracted all my data for a single field but when I try to get both FirstName and LastName I get unwanted output, e.g I receive string as follows ' FirstName = <Name> LastName = <Name>' in this format. I would like to get only the <Name> not the string FirstName as extra.

Comment: @user3123404: Well you'd use `x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName` or however you want to format it... fundamentally you've got two values, and you need to say how you want to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var student = context.Student 
                     .Where(student => student.StudentID == studentId)
                     .Select(student => new 
                      { 
                          FirstName = student.FirstName, 
                          LastName = student.LastName 
                      }).FirstOrDefault();
```

If any student with `studentId` exists at all, then you get her first name and her last name, like below:

```
var firstName = student.FirstName;
var lastName = student.LastName;
```

If there isn't any student with the given `studentId`, the result of the above query, would be `null`. Hence, before you use the *dot notation*, please validate that the user you are looking for has been found like below:

```
if(student!=null)
{
   // Here you can access both the LastName and 
   // the FirstName of the found student.
}
```

Comment: I don't know where to write this var firstName = student.FirstName, since when I try and write it below the code in question I don't seem to be able to reach student...

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like:
`var name = context.Students.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Id == SomeId).FirstName;`